# Pack project WPF, the library is missing class and method

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, pack

I have three project. A B C. A have reference to B, and B have reference to C.
I do pack on project A.

I added this to A.csproj to copy other dll to nuget:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage);SetCustomFilesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="SetCustomFilesToPackage">
    <ItemGroup>
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\*.dll">
            <PackagePath>lib/net461</PackagePath>
        </TfmSpecificPackageFile>
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\**\*.dll">
            <PackagePath>lib/net461</PackagePath>
        </TfmSpecificPackageFile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

When I browse nuget all dll files are in it. But when I use this nuget in other project there are missing whole class or some method form project B and C.

Why is it happen?

**Edit:**

I also noticed that library "B" fell into Dependencies when I open a nuget. And when I enter the classes that exist for "B" and "C", they have version 1.0.9, despite the fact that I do not currently version these projects. And project "A" has version 1.0.48.

Comment: you can do like this `<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="<dll path>">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>`

Comment: Look at working project.  the dll are in a folder lib. You need same folder where working or change the Package Path to a folder where reachable by other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding "C" to the
project reference "A" and setting PrivateAssets = "All" for ProjectReference. The result is that they don't show up in Dependency nuget's and work.